# Delete specific lines above current line in vim normal mode?

Tags: vim

<kbd>d7d</kbd> or <kbd>7dd</kbd> to delete next 7 lines, however, I want to delete the 7 lines above current line, what shoudl I do?

There is my thought, default <kbd>+</kbd> is following, <kbd>-</kbd> is above, So, I tried <kbd>d-7d</kbd> and <kbd>-7dd</kbd>, but failed.

So, In the end, I made a compromise, <kbd>7k</kbd> + <kbd>7dd</kbd> to delete the next 7 lines, it's really stupid.

After that, I thought a good idea, using vim visual mode. <kbd>shift +
 v</kbd> + <kbd>7k</kbd>, then <kbd>x</kbd>, It sounds better.

BTW, does there have other faster way ?
PS. I'm a perfectionist, I'll appreciate your reply.

SUMMARY:
<kbd>d7k</kbd> is the shortest solution.

Comment: you mean `d7k` ?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo, thanks for your reply, yes, you're right. I think most eaiest way is d7k .